# Command run in batch file behaves differently than run directly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to create `batch file` that creates service to run under NSSM.

The command I execute is:

```
nssm install myservice (gcm myservice).Path
```

While it runs perfectly when executed from PowerShell it doesn't return `path` to `myservice` when `batch` is executed. The resulting configuration of the service is:

```
Path: gcm
```

Why?

Comment: `gcm` is an alias for `Get-Command` - a PowerShell command not present in `cmd.exe`. In a batch file you'd have to do something like `for /F "tokens=*" %%n IN ('where myservice') DO @(nssm install myservice %%n)` (although I'd recommend just sticking with PowerShell)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Your solution works perfectly!